# Process.run: ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, dart

I'm trying to fix a library that doesn't work (for me) on latest dart version.

Right now the problems I'm facing comes from the following line in a test setup:

```
Process.runSync('pub', ['get'], workingDirectory: stubPath);
```

which errors out as:

```
ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified.

  Command: pub get

dart:io                             Process.runSync
test\test_coverage_test.dart 32:15  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

The `pub` executable is on my path and works well when  run manually from a shell. I checked and the dart process does receive the environment properly (PATH is set).

I'm working on windows 10, and tried running the test in both `powershell` and `cmd` and even in administrator.

The library worked well before upgrading from Dart 2.9.x to 2.12.1

Comment: Try give the full path to the pub executable. I am not sure if Dart at using the PATH variable.

Comment: It does not work and it would not be a working solution. The path of pub can change depending on which computer is executing the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue and I fixed passing the `runInShell: true` argument:

```dart
await Process.runSync('pub', ['get'], workingDirectory: yourWorkingDir, runInShell: true);
```